# Rails unable to save json in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql

I want to save Json data in my Rails PostgreSQL database.

In my migration file

```
class IbmSubscription < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :ibm_subscriptions do |t|
      t.json 'ibm_response'
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :ibm_subscriptions
  end    
end
```

I am unable to save JSON data in ibm_response
I tried this in rails console

```
2.1.5 :004 > a = JSON.parse(@uri.to_s)
 => {"type"=>"SUBSCRIPTION_ORDER", "marketplace"=>{"base_url"=>"https://acme.appdirect.com", "partner"=>"ACME"}, "flag"=>"STATELESS", "creator"=>{"email"=>"test-email+creator@appdirect.com", "first_name"=>"DummyCreatorFirst", "language"=>"fr", "last_name"=>"DummyCreatorLast", "open_id"=>"https://www.appdirect.com/openid/id/ec5d8eda-5cec-444d-9e30-125b6e4b67e2", "uuid"=>"ec5d8eda-5cec-444d-9e30-125b6e4b67e2"}, "payload"=>{"company"=>{"country"=>"CA", "email"=>"company-email@example.com", "name"=>"Example Company Name", "phone_number"=>"415-555-1212", "uuid"=>"d15bb36e-5fb5-11e0-8c3c-00262d2cda03", "website"=>"http://www.example.com"}, "configuration"=>{"entry"=>{"key"=>"domain", "value"=>"mydomain"}}, "order"=>{"edition_code"=>"BASIC", "pricing_duration"=>"MONTHLY", "item"=>[{"quantity"=>"10", "unit"=>"USER"}, {"quantity"=>"15", "unit"=>"MEGABYTE"}]}}, "return_url"=>"https://www.appdirect.com/finishprocure?token=dummyOrder", "@xmlns:atom"=>"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"} 
2.1.5 :005 > a = IbmSubscription.create(ibm_response: @uri)
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for IbmSubscription: ibm_response

   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (5.7ms)  INSERT INTO "ibm_subscriptions" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 02 Oct 2015 17:30:13 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 02 Oct 2015 17:30:13 UTC +00:00]]
   (93.9ms)  COMMIT
 => #<IbmSubscription id: 1, ibm_response: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: "2015-10-02 17:30:13", updated_at: "2015-10-02 17:30:13">
```

Its creating ibm_response: nil.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Don't you want to save `a` not `@uri` ?  Can you try `b = IbmSubscription.create(ibm_response: a)`

Comment: @Anthony Thats working but  I am not able to assign user_id .

Comment: `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for IbmSubscription: ibm_response` this is a key to solving your problem. Just google `Can't mass-assign protected attributes` this topic was brought up multiple times on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes for IbmSubscription

This line implies that you need to add `:ibm_response` to attr_accessible in your `IbmSubscription` model.

Comment: I am using rails 4 and its problem in only this model

Comment: Yes , i was not knowing that.